Linux ODBC c++ program fails during SQLConnect with get_charset_by_csname call， why?
crash stack
the belowing is my mainCoding, running in linux is crash, above picture is crash stack,  but I don't know why.  "MY_SQL_CHAR” is "SQLCHAR", but in windows is "SQLWCHAR", the coding in runing in windows is ok, It can connect to odbc success in windows. but running in linux is crash when execute sqlconnect.the odbc is connect to td-sql.
Besides, I try run the Similar  class in single project, I can run ok, but run in the big project, It will crash, the crash information is the same.
int COdbcConnect::Connect(const char* pDataSource)
{
    LOG_WARNING(g_pLogHandle, "xxxxxxxxxx, pDataSource:%s", pDataSource); ///test3
    m_strDataSource = std::string(pDataSource);
    SQLRETURN ret;
    if (m_pEnv == NULL)
    {
        if (false == initEnv(m_pEnv)) ///test3
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    UTIL_Strcpy(m_pEnv->dataSource, MAX_DATA_SOURCE_LENGTH, pDataSource);
 
    CloseConnect();
    try
    {
        ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &(m_pEnv->hEnv));

        if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        {
            m_bConnected = false;
            ONLY_CHECK_ERROR(ret,"Connect: when exec SQLAllocHandle",m_pEnv->hEnv,SQL_HANDLE_ENV)
            SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, m_pEnv->hEnv);
            return 2;
        }

        ret=SQLSetEnvAttr((m_pEnv->hEnv), SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
        if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        {
            m_bConnected = false;
            ONLY_CHECK_ERROR(ret,"Connect: when exec SQLAllocHandle",m_pEnv->hEnv,SQL_HANDLE_ENV)
                SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, m_pEnv->hEnv);
            return 3;
        }

        ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_pEnv->hEnv, &(m_pEnv->hDbc));
        if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
            m_bConnected = false;
            ONLY_CHECK_ERROR(ret,"Connect: allocate odbc connection handler",m_pEnv->hEnv,SQL_HANDLE_ENV);
            SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_pEnv->hDbc);
            SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, m_pEnv->hEnv);
            return 4;
        }

        LOG_WARNING(g_pLogHandle, "ret = %d, datasource = %p, %s, m_pEnv->hDbc:%p", ret, m_pEnv->dataSource, m_pEnv->dataSource, m_pEnv->hDbc); ///test3
        ret=SQLConnect((m_pEnv->hDbc), (MY_SQL_CHAR*)"smarteazy",
            SQL_NTS, (MY_SQL_CHAR *)NULL, SQL_NTS, (MY_SQL_CHAR *)NULL,
            SQL_NTS); ///test3
       //const char* pAbc = "smarteazy";
       //ret=SQLConnect((m_pEnv->hDbc), (MY_SQL_CHAR*)pAbc,
       //     SQL_NTS, (MY_SQL_CHAR *)NULL, SQL_NTS, (MY_SQL_CHAR *)NULL,
       //     SQL_NTS); ///test3
       //ret=SQLConnect((env->hDbc), (SQLCHAR*)env->data_source,
       //    SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR *)NULL, SQL_NTS, (SQLCHAR *)NULL,
       //    SQL_NTS);


        //LOG_WARNING(g_pLogHandle, "ret = %d， datasource = %s", ret, m_pEnv->dataSource); ///test3
        if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
            // 连接失败
            m_bConnected = false;
            ONLY_CHECK_ERROR(ret,"Connect: when exec SQLConnect",m_pEnv->hEnv,SQL_HANDLE_ENV);
            SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_pEnv->hDbc);
            SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, m_pEnv->hEnv);
            return 5;
        }


        ret = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, (m_pEnv->hDbc), &(m_pEnv->hStmt));
        if (ret != SQL_SUCCESS && ret != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
        {
            m_bConnected = false;
            ONLY_CHECK_ERROR(ret,"Connect: when exec SQLAllocHandle",m_pEnv->hEnv,SQL_HANDLE_ENV)
            SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, m_pEnv->hStmt);
            SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_pEnv->hDbc);
            SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, m_pEnv->hEnv);
            return 6;
        }
        else
        {
            m_bConnected = true;
        }
    }
    catch (char* pError)
    {
        LOG_WARNING(g_pLogHandle, "catch exception error:%s", pError);
        m_bConnected = false;
        ONLY_CHECK_ERROR(ret,"Connect: when exec SQLAllocHandle",m_pEnv->hEnv,SQL_HANDLE_ENV);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, m_pEnv->hStmt);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, m_pEnv->hDbc);
        SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, m_pEnv->hEnv);
        return 7;
    }

    return 0;
}

Above picture is the crash stack, but I don't know why.

(MY_SQL_CHAR*)"smarteazy" -- Do you get compile errors if you removed that (suspicious) cast?  If so, what compiler error is given?

../../Src/OdbcConnect.cpp:178:20: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘SQLCHAR* {aka unsigned char*}’ [-fpermissive]
SQL_NTS); ///test3
^
In file included from ../../Src/OdbcConnect.cpp:14:0:
/usr/local/unixodbc/include/sql.h:632:24: note:   initializing argument 2 of ‘SQLRETURN SQLConnect(SQLHDBC, SQLCHAR*, SQLSMALLINT, SQLCHAR*, SQLSMALLINT, SQLCHAR*, SQLSMALLINT)’
SQLRETURN  SQL_API SQLConnect(SQLHDBC ConnectionHandle,
^~~~~~~~~~
make: *** [Makefile:38: OdbcConnect.o] Error 1
@
PaulMcKenzie

error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘SQLCHAR* -- That argument requires a modifiable array of char, not a string-literal.  Never cast string arguments -- casting is not conversion.  Either supply the correct type, or call another function that accepts the type you are passing without casting.  By using a C-style cast, you told the compiler to "shut up, I know what I'm doing" when the compiler knows that you are doing something that is suspicious.

I wouldn't be surprised if removing all of those other casts reveals multiple compilation errors.  You can't simply sweep all the dirt under the rug by C-style casting away all of the compilation errors.

but is also report the same error, when I modify the code by belowing code.
const char* pAbc = "smarteazy"; MY_SQL_CHAR tempDataSource[128]; memset(tempDataSource, 0, sizeof(tempDataSource)); for (int nIndex = 0; ;nIndex++) {     tempDataSource[nIndex] = pAbc[nIndex];     if (tempDataSource[nIndex] == '\0')     {         break;     } } ret=SQLConnect((m_pEnv->hDbc), tempDataSource,     SQL_NTS, NULL, SQL_NTS, NULL,     SQL_NTS);  @PaulMcKenzie

Besides, I try run the Similar class in single project, I can run ok, but run in the big project, It will crash, the crash information is the same.@PaulMcKenzie
